# How to delete every closed milestone with gitlab api

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-api

Since we're a small team, we set the milestone with the number of the week. ex: `week - 12`.

But then, when started a new year, we cannot create those milestone anymore because they already exists and are closed.

I would like to delete every closed milestone and tried to use the [giltab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/group_milestones.html) for this purpose.

I've created the follwing script :

requesting every closed milestone *working*

```sh
# global.sh
get_closed_milestones(){
  curl -s -H "$private_token" \
  -X GET \
  "${base_url}groups/${group_name}/milestones?state=closed"
}

remove_milestone() {
 # echo result: https://gitlab.entepriseName.ch/api/v4/groups/entepriseName/milestones/279  
  curl -H "$private_token" \
  -X DELETE \
  "${base_url}groups/${group_name}/milestones/$1"
}
```

making a loop and deleting it

```sh
# milestone-remover.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Importes
source ./includes/global.sh

issues=$(get_closed_milestones)

  for milestone_id in $(jq -c '.[] | .id'<<< "$issues"); do

  milestone_id=${milestone_id%/r}


  # If not null
    if [ ! "$milestone_id" == "null/r" ];
    then
     remove_milestone "$milestone_id"
    fi

  done
```

I had to use the  `! "$milestone_id" == "null/r"` cause I realize I did get null like this.
It is looking a bit stang but it did send the request. I'll then had this response

```
+ curl -H 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxx' -X DELETE $'https://gitlab.entepriseName.ch/api/v4/groups/entepriseName/milestones/293\r'
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

Does somebody see an error?

Comment: `"''/milestones/'"$1"''` what is going on with the quotes there? Do you see the syntax highlight here? `milestone_id= echo` that's not how you set a variable. Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net . And `/r` is literally `/` and `r`. To have CR character, do `$'\r'`. But I do not think there should be CR characters coming from gitlab, that would be stranfe..

Comment: I'm quite a beginner with bash script, sry. `"''/milestones/'"$1"''` takes the `$milestone_id` and assign it at the end of the request. `milestone_id= echo` I did see this on another chat. ` To have CR character, do $'\r'` I want to remove those characters, no clue why it cames with gitlab, maybe it's because of the way I did the loop? Could you help me on that?

Comment: To remove do `milestone_id=${milestone_id%$'/r'}` or use `dox2unix`. `takes the $milestone_id` Sure, but why all the `'` quotes sprinkled everywhere? Just `"${base_url}groups/$group_name/milestones/$1"` - just two `"`. Also don't you see the unclosed `?state=closed'` `'` quote? Did you check your script with shellcheck.net ?

Comment: Thx for your explanation, I did refactor my code and do not get warnings from shellcheck anymore. But the code still doesn't works

Comment: Then now you go to debuging. Research how to debug bash scripts - add `set -x` and post the output - there is something wrong with the curl call.

Comment: Thx a lot, it did help me saw that I had `/r` at the end of the request. I it now working with `milestone_id="${milestone_id%%[[:cntrl:]]}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove to remove the `/r` that was in the `$milestone_id` variable with the following code `milestone_id="${milestone_id%%[[:cntrl:]]}"`

This is the final code

```sh
issues=$(get_closed_milestones)

  for milestone_id in $(jq -c '.[] | .id'<<< "$issues"); do

  milestone_id="${milestone_id%%[[:cntrl:]]}"


  # If not null
    if [ ! "$milestone_id" == "null/r" ];
    then
     remove_milestone "$milestone_id"
    fi

  done
```